# Getting a Set-SPOsite Error

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, onedrive, sharepoint-online

i have the following code
its to mass enable External Sharing on SPO and OD users

```
Connect-SPOService -Url https://######-admin.sharepoint.com

$currentSiteCollection = (Get-Content "siteCollectionsEnabled.txt")
$collectionCount = $currentSiteCollection.Count
if ($currentSiteCollection){
    foreach ($currentSite in $currentSiteCollection)
    {
    Clear-Host
        Write-Output "Enabling " $currentSite.ToString() $collectionCount.ToString() " sites left"
        Set-SPOSite -Identity $currentSite -SharingCapability ExternalUserSharingOnly
    Add-Content ODFBSiteSharingEnabled.log $currentSite.ToString()
        $collectionCount = $collectionCount - 1 
    }
}
```

but when running i get this
8741
 sites left
Set-SPOSite : No connection available. Use Connect-SPOService before running this CmdLet.
At C:###\siteCollectionsDisabledEnable\siteEnable.ps1:10 char:9
+         Set-SPOSite -Identity $currentSite -SharingCapability ExternalUserSharin ...
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Set-SPOSite], InvalidOperationException

some help here?

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to run Connect-SPOService cmdlet on its own? Do you get any error?

If it works fine and you are able to sign in, then remove the first line of your script here and execute the rest of it.